# Use bpy to render bake only the active material's active image

Tags: python, texture-baking, baking

When I click render bake, it will render the active image for every material on an object. I would instead like to only bake the active material. Is there a way to do this that doesn't require separating the mesh by material before the bake?

```
import bpy
obj = active_object
active_material = obj.active_materialk
for slot in obj.material_slots:
    if slot.material != active_material:
        #disable material for rendering somehow
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='EMIT')
```

Here's an example file with two materials setup and all relevant work spaces:
[image]

[image]